# Get exc_bad_access error code when using SDWebImage and UIProgressView

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview, sdwebimage

I'm using UICollectionView + SDWebImage to display image grid.
In custom cell, i defined UIProgressView to display progress bar for display image loading progress.

Here is my code:

```
cell.ImageInCell.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL.URLWithString("\(apifileurl)"),placeholderImage: previewimg.image, options: nil,
            progress: {(receivedSize: Int,expectedSize: Int) in
                var prog:Float = Float(receivedSize)/Float(expectedSize)
                cell.LoadingLine.setProgress(prog, animated: 1)
            }, completed: {(image: UIImage?,error: NSError?,cacheType: SDImageCacheType,imageURL: NSURL?) in
                if( image != nil ) {
                    cell.LoadingLine.setProgress(0, animated: 0)
                }
        })
```

Trouble is when i scroll too fast, i received error:
exc_bad_access error code 2.

When i removed line:

```
cell.LoadingLine.setProgress(prog, animated: 1)
```

Everything work fine. 
Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you run `NSLog("\(prog)")` right before your `setProgress` call?

Comment: setProgress working fine. it's printing completed parts of downloading image.